# How to pass data from flask to javascript without render_template

Tags: javascript, python, flask

how can I pass data, actually file's base64 code, straight from flask(python) to javascript, but without using render_template or redirect?

I need to do that, because send_from_directory is downloading .pdf file straight to user's computer, I need just a pre-view of .pdf file, so I get file's code by .read(), encode with base64, and what I want to do is decode that in js/jquery and generate new pdf with that code.

Comment: Why don't you consider passing the pdf file in base64 encoded format through a json string? And why is that you do not want to use render_template. Anyways it is not going to transmit the file to a user's machine if you use it rightly

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data to your javascript app as JSON from Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

@app.route(..)
def fn_name():
    # logic here
    # pdf_base64 is variable containing data
    return jsonify(result=pdf_base64)
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.